# Spell checker in C

Tags: c, data-structures

The problem statement:

> Write a program in C to spell-check the given article file (`article.txt`) with the given dictionary file (`dictionary.txt`). Print all wrong words and words with its position in the article that don't exist in the dictionary in `misspelling.txt`
> Some requirements include:
>
> 1. If a word is in upper case, change it to lower first.
> 2. Some wrong words may occur several times in the article. You need to print all of its positions. The position of a word is its first letter's position in the file, counting from 0.
>
> [Here](https://gist.github.com/wendingp/550e669616a28c1077f6988e84350e43) is an example including the expected output `misspelling.txt`.

The final test actually uses the Bible as the `article.txt`, and the dictionary is also much bigger than that in the example. [Here](https://gist.github.com/wendingp/550e669616a28c1077f6988e84350e43#file-first_ten_lines_of_expected_output-txt) are the first 10 lines of the
expected output given by the online judge.

I use a trie to store the dictionary. My code gives the same output as the example but fails the final test with `SIGSEGV` fault. I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum {
    MAX_NUMBER_OF_NODES = 1500000, NUM_OF_ALPHA = 26, MAX_LENGTH_OF_WORD = 100,
    MAX_OCCURENCE_OF_SAME_WRONG_WORD = 10000, MAX_NUMBER_OF_WRONG_WORDS = 600000,
};
int trie[MAX_NUMBER_OF_NODES][NUM_OF_ALPHA + 1], next = 0;
typedef long long ll;

void build_trie(char s[]) {
    ll i, t = 1;
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        if (isupper(s[i])) {
            s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
        }
        int pos = s[i] - 'a';
        if (trie[t][pos] == 0) {
            trie[t][pos] = ++next;
        }
        t = trie[t][pos];
    }
}

/* Checks if the trie contains the string s.
 * Returns 1 if contains; 0 if not. */
ll contains(char s[]) {
    ll i, t = 1;
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        int pos = s[i] - 'a';
        if (trie[t][pos] == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        t = trie[t][pos];
    }
    return 1;
}

ll current_pos = 0;
static inline int f_getc(FILE *fp) {
    int c = fgetc(fp);
    if (c != EOF)
        current_pos++;
    return c;
}

ll get_word(char s[], FILE *in) {
    ll c, begin_of_word, lim = MAX_LENGTH_OF_WORD;
    char *w = s;
    while (isspace(c = f_getc(in)) || isdigit(c)) {  /* Skips spaces and digits. */
        ;
    }
    if (c != EOF) {
        *w++ = tolower(c);
        begin_of_word = current_pos;
    }
    if (!isalpha(c)) {
        *w = '\0';
        return c;
    }
    for (; --lim > 0; ++w) {
        if (!isalpha(c = f_getc(in))) { /* End of word. */
            break;
        }
        *w = tolower(c);
    }
    *w = '\0';
    return begin_of_word;
}

typedef struct WrongWord WrongWord;
struct WrongWord {
    char word[MAX_LENGTH_OF_WORD];
    ll pos;
};

int wrong_word_cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    return strcmp((*(const WrongWord **)p1)->word, (*(const WrongWord **)p2)->word);
}

int ll_cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    return *((const ll **) p1) - *((const ll **) p2);
}

WrongWord *wrong_word_list[MAX_NUMBER_OF_WRONG_WORDS];
void spell_check() {
    /* Builds the trie from dictionary.txt .*/
    FILE *dict = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
    if (!dict) {
        fprintf(stderr, "dictionary.txt cannot be opened!\n");
        return;
    }
    char word[MAX_LENGTH_OF_WORD];
    while (fgets(word, sizeof word, dict)) {
        word[strcspn(word, "\r\n")] = 0;
        build_trie(word);
    }
    fclose(dict);
    FILE *in = fopen("article.txt", "r");
    if (!in) {
        fprintf(stderr, "article.txt cannot be opened\n");
        return;
    }
    char str[MAX_LENGTH_OF_WORD];
    ll begin_of_word, wrong_word_count = 0;
    while ((begin_of_word = get_word(str, in)) != EOF) {
        if (!contains(str)) {
            WrongWord *wwp = malloc(sizeof(WrongWord));
            if (!wwp) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!\n");
                return;
            }
            strcpy(wwp->word, str);
            wwp->pos = begin_of_word;
            wrong_word_list[wrong_word_count++] = wwp;
        }
    }
    qsort(wrong_word_list, wrong_word_count, sizeof wrong_word_list[0], wrong_word_cmp);

    /* Adds a sentinel node. */
    wrong_word_list[wrong_word_count] = malloc(sizeof wrong_word_list[0]);
    strcpy(wrong_word_list[wrong_word_count++]->word, "");

    /* Prints the result into misspelling.txt */
    FILE *out = fopen("misspelling.txt", "w");
    if (!out) {
        fprintf(stderr, "misspelling.txt cannot be opened!\n");
        return;
    }
    char last_word[MAX_LENGTH_OF_WORD] = "";
    ll i, j, pos[MAX_OCCURENCE_OF_SAME_WRONG_WORD], count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < wrong_word_count; ++i) {
        if (strcmp(last_word, wrong_word_list[i]->word)) {  /* Meets a new word. */
            if (*last_word) {  /* Prints the last word if exists. */
                fprintf(out, "%s ", last_word);
                qsort(pos, count, sizeof pos[0], ll_cmp);
                for (j = 0; j < count; ++j) {
                    fprintf(out, "%lld%c", pos[j], j == count - 1 ? '\n' : ' ');
                }
            }
            count = 0;
            strcpy(last_word, wrong_word_list[i]->word);
            pos[count++] = wrong_word_list[i]->pos;
        } else {  /* Same word. */
            pos[count++] = wrong_word_list[i]->pos;
        }
    }
    fclose(out);
}

int main() {
    spell_check();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use gdb, then valgrind, analyze the outcome.

Comment: You can also use hashing, it should be much faster than a tree "O(1)" instead "O(log n)", and less efford to program

Comment: The code structure leaves a lot to be desired.  I'd expect separate functions to read the dictionary and process the words in the document.  The file names should be passed as arguments to the function, not hard-coded in the function.  Shouldn't you simply build a trie of the invalid words?  It means you have just one structure type to represent both valid and invalid words.

Comment: @Thomas but it needs to check the whole word, every letter.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't get it. Trie is efficient for searching, but when I need to print the invalid words, I don't think a trie is useful.

Comment: @pwd you can write a hashtable with all valid words. Afterwarts you itterate through the testfile words. And check if the word is inside

Comment: Ahh your tree is filled letter by letter... OK, that is fast

Comment: OK; do it your way — no problem to me.  But if a misspelled word appears 20 times in the document, you are probably supposed to list it once with the 20 locations.  Maybe that is an argument against the trie — or maybe not.  I've not sat down and coded it.  But if the printout of the misspelled words is to be done in dictionary order, then the trie structure makes that simple.  You simply need to be able to store more information (an indefinite list of positions where the misspelled word occurs) for any given word.

Comment: @Thomas I know hashing, but FYI, trie is not a tree, it is O(L), L is the length of the word. And it can "quick drop", i.e. stop quicker than hashing.

Comment: And tries never run into collisions; hashes might (though a good hash won't).

Comment: FWIW: Given `article.txt` containing just `THE KING JAMES BIBLE - PUBLIC DOMAIN  From: Bill McGinnis Ministries - "Feeding His Sheep"` (actually spread over 5 lines, 3 of them blank), I get the program crashing on the word `McGinnis` — and the debugger and/or malloc debugging seems to indicate problems with heap overwriting.  I've not tracked down why that happens.  Dunno if that reproduces for you.  I can't run [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) on macOS Sierra — it's broken at the moment.  But you should look to run Valgrind on the code; it will probably help diagnose what's wrong.

Comment: The longest word in the Oxford dictionary is `28-chars` (requiring `29` if stored as a string), you are using only `26`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I use MAX_LENGTH_OF_WORD = 100

Comment: I see that and `NUM_OF_ALPHA = 26` used in `trie[MAX_NUMBER_OF_NODES][NUM_OF_ALPHA + 1]` leading to the question whether storage for the content of your `dictionary.txt` is sufficient.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Your example is OK on my mac OS Sierra... no crash. But the [output](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wendingp/550e669616a28c1077f6988e84350e43/raw/0f5b1e6d6d14705298f8194403e1ee930d630d6f/misspelling_1.txt) is wrong and weird though, don't know why.

Comment: I've just recreated the code on another Mac, and when I add `printf("%lld: [%s]\n", begin_of_word, s);` before the return at the end of `get_word()`, it still crashes on [mcginnis].  The material shown was sufficient to crash it, it seems.  I got the bible from http://www.patriot.net/users/bmcgin/kjv12.zip; it is documented as being public domain.  Finally, [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is available and working on macOS Sierra again (the version is 3.13.0.SVN built from SVN — not the formal release version which is still 3.12.0). _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ Valgrind reports `invalid write of size 8` at `1 byte inside a block of 8 bytes`.  The line is `strcpy(wwp->word, str);` just before `wwp->pos = begin_of_word;` — and the `malloc()` is `WrongWord *wwp = malloc(sizeof wrong_word_list[0]);`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler why is that invalid?

Comment: Hmmm; that `1 byte inside` is puzzling.  When I compile with Clang (from XCode (Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)) instead of GCC 7.1.0, I get different behaviour — it crashes, but a lot later in the processing.  When I compile with GCC 6.2.0, it crashes the same as GCC 7.1.0.  Ick!

Comment: The Clang-compiled program get 51,000+ words (and offset just over 616,000 bytes) into the file before it crashes.  I wonder if this is overflowing one of your fixed size allocations.  Adding some more instrumentation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler but I use the given small dictionary, your example still produces wrong answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144612/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-pwd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First pass

Upon further investigation, primarily using assertions to find the problem, the issue is that `get_word()` doesn't necessarily return strings of alphabetic characters, and the `contains()` function doesn't ensure that the data is alphabetic but treats non-alphabetic data (e.g. a string `"-"`) as if it was, subtracting `'a'` from `'-'` and using that as an index into the trie structure.  Since the value is `-52`, it is at best indeterminate what value it is looking at.

Here is fixed code.  The `main()` program now accepts arguments — the file names it is to process.  The usage is crude, but effective enough (the name `sc61` is what I used for the program compiled from `sc61.c`):

```
Usage: sc61 [dictionary [article [misspellings]]]
```

I did testing with invocations such as:

```
sc61 new.dictionary great.panjandrum /dev/stdout
```

or:

```
sc61 dictionary.txt bible12.txt
```

The code also frees the wrong word list, and runs clean under Valgrind 3.13.0.SVN on macOS Sierra 10.12.5 (at last Valgrind is working on macOS!).

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum {
    MAX_NUMBER_OF_NODES = 1500000, NUM_OF_ALPHA = 26, MAX_LENGTH_OF_WORD = 100,
    MAX_OCCURENCE_OF_SAME_WRONG_WORD = 10000, MAX_NUMBER_OF_WRONG_WORDS = 600000,
};
int trie[MAX_NUMBER_OF_NODES][NUM_OF_ALPHA + 1], next = 0;
typedef long long ll;

void build_trie(char s[]);
bool contains(char s[]);
ll get_word(char s[], FILE *in);
int wrong_word_cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2);
int ll_cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2);
void spell_check(const char *dictionary, const char *article, const char *misspelling);

void build_trie(char s[])
{
    ll i, t = 1;
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if (isupper(s[i]))
        {
            s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
        }
        int pos = s[i] - 'a';
        if (trie[t][pos] == 0)
        {
            assert(next < MAX_NUMBER_OF_NODES);
            trie[t][pos] = ++next;
        }
        t = trie[t][pos];
    }
}

/* Check if the trie contains the string s */
bool contains(char s[])
{
    ll i, t = 1;
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        assert(isalpha((unsigned char)s[i]));
        int pos = tolower((unsigned char)s[i]) - 'a';
        if (pos < 0 || pos > NUM_OF_ALPHA)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Assertion: [%s] %lld == %c (pos = %d)\n", s, i, s[i], pos);
        }
        assert(pos >= 0 && pos <= NUM_OF_ALPHA);
        if (trie[t][pos] == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        t = trie[t][pos];
    }
    return true;
}

ll current_pos = 0;

static inline int f_getc(FILE *fp)
{
    int c = fgetc(fp);
    if (c != EOF)
        current_pos++;
    return c;
}

ll get_word(char s[], FILE *in)
{
    ll c, begin_of_word = 0, lim = MAX_LENGTH_OF_WORD;
    char *w = s;
    while (!isalpha(c = f_getc(in)) && c != EOF)
        ;
    assert(isalpha(c) || c == EOF);
    if (c == EOF)
    {
        *w = '\0';
        return c;
    }
    *w++ = tolower(c);
    begin_of_word = current_pos;
    for ( ; --lim > 0; ++w)
    {
        if (!isalpha(c = f_getc(in)))   /* End of word. */
        {
            //current_pos = w + 1 - s + begin_of_word;
            break;
        }
        *w = tolower(c);
    }
    *w = '\0';
    printf("%s: %lld %zu [%s]\n", __func__, begin_of_word, strlen(s), s);
    return begin_of_word;
}

typedef struct WrongWord WrongWord;
struct WrongWord
{
    char word[MAX_LENGTH_OF_WORD];
    ll pos;
};

int wrong_word_cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    return strcmp((*(const WrongWord **)p1)->word, (*(const WrongWord **)p2)->word);
}

int ll_cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    return *((const ll **)p1) - *((const ll **)p2);
}

WrongWord *wrong_word_list[MAX_NUMBER_OF_WRONG_WORDS];

static void read_dictionary(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (dict == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "file '%s' cannot be opened for reading\n", dictionary);
        return;
    }
    char word[MAX_LENGTH_OF_WORD];
    while (fgets(word, sizeof word, dict))
    {
        word[strcspn(word, "\r\n")] = 0;
        build_trie(word);
    }
    fclose(dict);
}

void spell_check(const char *dictionary, const char *article, const char *misspelling)
{
    /* Builds the trie from dictionary .*/
    read_dictionary(dictionary);

    FILE *in = fopen(article, "r");
    if (!in)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "file '%s' cannot be opened for reading\n", article);
        return;
    }
    char str[MAX_LENGTH_OF_WORD];
    ll begin_of_word = 0;
    ll wrong_word_count = 0;
    while ((begin_of_word = get_word(str, in)) != EOF)
    {
        if (!contains(str))
        {
            //WrongWord *wwp = malloc(sizeof wrong_word_list[0]);
            WrongWord *wwp = malloc(sizeof(*wwp));
            static int done = 0;
            if (!done)
                printf("Sizes: %zu %zu %zu\n", sizeof(wrong_word_list[0]), sizeof(*wwp), sizeof(WrongWord)), done++;
            if (!wwp)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!\n");
                return;
            }
            printf("%s: %lld %zu [%s] %lld\n", __func__, begin_of_word, strlen(str), str, wrong_word_count+1);
            strcpy(wwp->word, str);
            wwp->pos = begin_of_word;
            wrong_word_list[wrong_word_count++] = wwp;
        }
    }
    fclose(in);
    qsort(wrong_word_list, wrong_word_count, sizeof wrong_word_list[0], wrong_word_cmp);

    /* Adds a sentinel node. */
    wrong_word_list[wrong_word_count] = malloc(sizeof wrong_word_list[0]);
    strcpy(wrong_word_list[wrong_word_count++]->word, "");

    /* Prints the result into misspelling.txt */
    FILE *out = fopen(misspelling, "w");
    if (!out)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "file '%s' cannot be opened for writing\n", misspelling);
        return;
    }
    char last_word[MAX_LENGTH_OF_WORD] = "";
    ll i, j, pos[MAX_OCCURENCE_OF_SAME_WRONG_WORD], count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < wrong_word_count; ++i)
    {
        if (strcmp(last_word, wrong_word_list[i]->word))    /* Meets a new word. */
        {
            if (*last_word)    /* Prints the last word if exists. */
            {
                fprintf(out, "%s ", last_word);
                qsort(pos, count, sizeof pos[0], ll_cmp);
                for (j = 0; j < count; ++j)
                {
                    fprintf(out, "%lld%c", pos[j], j == count - 1 ? '\n' : ' ');
                }
            }
            count = 0;
            strcpy(last_word, wrong_word_list[i]->word);
            pos[count++] = wrong_word_list[i]->pos;
            assert(count < MAX_OCCURENCE_OF_SAME_WRONG_WORD);
        }
        else      /* Same word. */
        {
            pos[count++] = wrong_word_list[i]->pos;
            assert(count < MAX_OCCURENCE_OF_SAME_WRONG_WORD);
        }
    }
    fclose(out);

    /* free wrong word list */
    for (int i = 0; i < wrong_word_count; i++)
    {
        free(wrong_word_list[i]);
    }
    wrong_word_count = 0;

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *dictionary = "dictionary.txt";
    const char *article = "article.txt";
    const char *misspelling = "misspelling.txt";
    if (argc > 1)
        dictionary = argv[1];
    if (argc > 2)
        article = argv[2];
    if (argc > 3)
        misspelling = argv[3];
    spell_check(dictionary, article, misspelling);
    return 0;
}
```

Given the file [`great.panjandrum`](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Grand_Panjandrum) containing:

```
So she went into the garden
to cut a cabbage-leaf
to make an apple-pie
and at the same time
a great she-bear coming down the street
pops its head into the shop
What no soap
So he died
and she very imprudently married the Barber
and there were present
the Picninnies
and the Joblillies
and the Garyulies
and the great Panjandrum himself
with the little round button at top
and they all fell to playing the game of catch-as-catch-can
till the gunpowder ran out at the heels of their boots
```

and running:

```
sc61 dictionary.txt great.panjandrum
```

the output file `misspelling.txt` is:

```
apple 62
barber 222
bear 105
boots 482
button 359
cabbage 38
catch 414 423
coming 110
cut 32
died 180
down 117
fell 386
game 406
garden 22
garyulies 294
gunpowder 442
head 142
heels 467
himself 329
imprudently 198
its 138
joblillies 275
leaf 46
married 210
panjandrum 318
picninnies 256
pie 68
playing 394
pops 133
present 244
ran 452
same 83
she 4 101 189
shop 156
soap 169
street 126
they 377
till 433
top 369
very 193
went 8
were 239
```

NB: the code shown counts from offset 1 (the first character of the file is at offset 1).  If you want it to have offset 0, change the line in `get_word()` which currently reads:

```
    begin_of_word = current_pos;
```

so that it reads:

```
    begin_of_word = current_pos - 1;
```

You might prefer to add `assert(current_pos > 0);` before it, or you might not be worried about that (the assertion doesn't fire, so it isn't critical).

#### Second pass

After considerable discussion via email, it became clear that there were a couple of other problems too.

- The trie building code is flawed in that it doesn't mark when a word ends at this point in the trie.
- Consequently, the search code couldn't tell whether a word was complete, so any prefix of a word was deemed correctly spelled.

The revisions in the trie handling are fairly minor, but crucial.
The code as a whole is considerably extended, with multiple command line options, debugging and timing.
The code uses library code available from GitHub at https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq.  The code for this answer is also on GitHub at https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-4404-0027 (the program above is basically `sc19.c` and the code below is `sc59.c`).

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "stderr.h"
#include "timer.h"

enum
{
    MAX_NUMBER_OF_NODES = 1200000,
    NUM_OF_ALPHA = 26,
    MAX_LENGTH_OF_WORD = 100,
    MAX_OCCURENCE_OF_SAME_WRONG_WORD = 10000,
    MAX_NUMBER_OF_WRONG_WORDS = 15000,
};
typedef long long ll;

static void build_trie(char s[]);
static bool contains(char s[]);
static ll get_word(char s[], FILE *in);
static int wrong_word_cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2);
static int ll_cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2);
static void spell_check(const char *dictionary, const char *article, const char *misspelling);

static int trie[MAX_NUMBER_OF_NODES][NUM_OF_ALPHA + 1];
static int next = 0;
static int debug = 0;
static bool timing = false;
static bool sizing = false;

static void build_trie(char s[])
{
    int i, t = 0;
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if (isupper(s[i]))
        {
            s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
        }
        int pos = s[i] - 'a';
        if (trie[t][pos] == 0)
        {
            assert(next < MAX_NUMBER_OF_NODES);
            trie[t][pos] = ++next;
        }
        t = trie[t][pos];
    }
    trie[t][NUM_OF_ALPHA] = 1;
}

static void dump_trie_from(const char *sofar, int node)
{
    int len = strlen(sofar);
    char buffer[len+2];
    strcpy(buffer, sofar);
    buffer[len + 1] = '\0';
    if (trie[node][NUM_OF_ALPHA] == 1)
        printf("word: [%s]\n", sofar);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ALPHA; i++)
    {
        if (trie[node][i] != 0)
        {
            buffer[len] = i + 'a';
            dump_trie_from(buffer, trie[node][i]);
        }
    }
}

/* Check if the trie contains the string s */
static bool contains(char s[])
{
    ll i, t = 0;
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        assert(isalpha((unsigned char)s[i]));
        int pos = tolower((unsigned char)s[i]) - 'a';
        if (pos < 0 || pos > NUM_OF_ALPHA)
            fprintf(stderr, "Assertion: [%s] %lld == %c (pos = %d)\n", s, i, s[i], pos);
        assert(pos >= 0 && pos <= NUM_OF_ALPHA);
        if (trie[t][pos] == 0)
            return false;
        t = trie[t][pos];
    }
    if (trie[t][NUM_OF_ALPHA] == 0)
        return false;
    return true;
}

static ll current_pos = 0;

static inline int f_getc(FILE *fp)
{
    int c = fgetc(fp);
    if (c != EOF)
        current_pos++;
    return c;
}

static ll get_word(char s[], FILE *in)
{
    ll c, begin_of_word = 0, lim = MAX_LENGTH_OF_WORD;
    char *w = s;
    while (!isalpha(c = f_getc(in)) && c != EOF)
        ;
    assert(isalpha(c) || c == EOF);
    if (c == EOF)
    {
        *w = '\0';
        return c;
    }
    *w++ = tolower(c);
    assert(current_pos > 0);
    begin_of_word = current_pos - 1;
    for ( ; --lim > 0; ++w)
    {
        if (!isalpha(c = f_getc(in)))
            break;
        *w = tolower(c);
    }
    *w = '\0';
    if (debug)
        printf("%s: %lld %zu [%s]\n", __func__, begin_of_word, strlen(s), s);
    return begin_of_word;
}

typedef struct WrongWord WrongWord;
struct WrongWord
{
    char word[MAX_LENGTH_OF_WORD];
    ll pos;
};

static int wrong_word_cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    return strcmp((*(const WrongWord **)p1)->word, (*(const WrongWord **)p2)->word);
}

static int ll_cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    return *((const ll **)p1) - *((const ll **)p2);
}

static WrongWord *wrong_word_list[MAX_NUMBER_OF_WRONG_WORDS];

static void read_dictionary(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (dict == NULL)
        err_syserr("file '%s' cannot be opened for reading\n", dictionary);
    char word[MAX_LENGTH_OF_WORD];
    while (fgets(word, sizeof word, dict))
    {
        word[strcspn(word, "\r\n")] = 0;
        build_trie(word);
    }
    fclose(dict);
    if (sizing)
        printf("Trie size: %d (out of %d: %6.2f%%)\n", next, MAX_NUMBER_OF_NODES,
               ((100.0 * next) / MAX_NUMBER_OF_NODES));
    if (debug)
        dump_trie_from("", 0);
}

static void spell_check(const char *dictionary, const char *article, const char *misspelling)
{
    Clock clk;
    clk_init(&clk);

    /* Builds the trie from dictionary .*/
    clk_start(&clk);
    read_dictionary(dictionary);
    clk_stop(&clk);
    if (timing)
    {
        char buffer[32];
        printf("Build: %s s\n", clk_elapsed_us(&clk, buffer, sizeof(buffer)));
    }

    clk_start(&clk);
    FILE *in = fopen(article, "r");
    if (!in)
        err_syserr("file '%s' cannot be opened for reading\n", article);
    char str[MAX_LENGTH_OF_WORD];
    ll begin_of_word = 0;
    ll wrong_word_count = 0;
    while ((begin_of_word = get_word(str, in)) != EOF)
    {
        if (!contains(str))
        {
            //WrongWord *wwp = malloc(sizeof wrong_word_list[0]);
            WrongWord *wwp = malloc(sizeof(*wwp));
            static int done = 0;
            if (debug && !done)
                printf("Sizes: %zu %zu %zu\n", sizeof(wrong_word_list[0]), sizeof(*wwp), sizeof(WrongWord)), done++;
            if (!wwp)
                err_error("Out of memory error!\n");
            if (debug)
                printf("%s: %lld %zu [%s] %lld\n", __func__, begin_of_word, strlen(str), str, wrong_word_count+1);
            strcpy(wwp->word, str);
            wwp->pos = begin_of_word;
            wrong_word_list[wrong_word_count++] = wwp;
        }
    }
    fclose(in);
    clk_stop(&clk);
    if (timing)
    {
        char buffer[32];
        printf("Scan: %s s\n", clk_elapsed_us(&clk, buffer, sizeof(buffer)));
    }
    if (sizing)
        printf("Number of wrong words: %lld (out of %d: %6.2f%%)\n", wrong_word_count, MAX_NUMBER_OF_WRONG_WORDS,
               ((100.0 * wrong_word_count) / MAX_NUMBER_OF_WRONG_WORDS));

    clk_start(&clk);
    qsort(wrong_word_list, wrong_word_count, sizeof wrong_word_list[0], wrong_word_cmp);

    /* Adds a sentinel node. */
    wrong_word_list[wrong_word_count] = malloc(sizeof wrong_word_list[0]);
    strcpy(wrong_word_list[wrong_word_count++]->word, "");

    /* Prints the result into misspelling.txt */
    FILE *out = fopen(misspelling, "w");
    if (!out)
        err_syserr("file '%s' cannot be opened for writing\n", misspelling);
    char last_word[MAX_LENGTH_OF_WORD] = "";
    ll i, j, pos[MAX_OCCURENCE_OF_SAME_WRONG_WORD], count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < wrong_word_count; ++i)
    {
        if (strcmp(last_word, wrong_word_list[i]->word))    /* Meets a new word. */
        {
            if (*last_word)    /* Prints the last word if exists. */
            {
                fprintf(out, "%s ", last_word);
                qsort(pos, count, sizeof pos[0], ll_cmp);
                for (j = 0; j < count; ++j)
                {
                    fprintf(out, "%lld%c", pos[j], j == count - 1 ? '\n' : ' ');
                }
            }
            count = 0;
            strcpy(last_word, wrong_word_list[i]->word);
            pos[count++] = wrong_word_list[i]->pos;
            assert(count < MAX_OCCURENCE_OF_SAME_WRONG_WORD);
        }
        else      /* Same word. */
        {
            pos[count++] = wrong_word_list[i]->pos;
            assert(count < MAX_OCCURENCE_OF_SAME_WRONG_WORD);
        }
    }
    fclose(out);
    clk_stop(&clk);
    if (timing)
    {
        char buffer[32];
        printf("Print: %s s\n", clk_elapsed_us(&clk, buffer, sizeof(buffer)));
    }

    /* free wrong word list */
    for (int i = 0; i < wrong_word_count; i++)
    {
        free(wrong_word_list[i]);
    }
    wrong_word_count = 0;
}

static const char optstr[] = "Dd:ha:o:st";
static const char usestr[] = "[-Dhst][-d dictionary][-a article][-o output]";
static const char hlpstr[] =
    "  -d dictionary  Use named dictionary file (default dictionary.txt)\n"
    "  -D             Enable debug output\n"
    "  -a article     Use named article file (default article.txt)\n"
    "  -h             Print this help message and exit\n"
    "  -o output      Use named file for output (default misspelling.txt)\n"
    "  -s             Print sizing information\n"
    "  -t             Time dictionary loading, article scanning, printing\n"
    ;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *def_dictionary = "dictionary.txt";
    const char *def_article = "article.txt";
    const char *def_misspelling = "misspelling.txt";
    const char *dictionary = 0;
    const char *article = 0;
    const char *misspelling = 0;

    err_setarg0(argv[0]);

    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, optstr)) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'D':
            debug = 1;
            break;
        case 'd':
            dictionary = optarg;
            break;
        case 'h':
            err_help(usestr, hlpstr);
            /*NOTREACHED*/
        case 'a':
            article = optarg;
            break;
        case 'o':
            misspelling = optarg;
            break;
        case 's':
            sizing = true;
            break;
        case 't':
            timing = true;
            break;
        default:
            err_usage(usestr);
            /*NOTREACHED*/
        }
    }
    if (argc != optind)
        err_usage(usestr);

    if (dictionary == 0)
        dictionary = def_dictionary;
    if (article == 0)
        article = def_article;
    if (misspelling == 0)
        misspelling = def_misspelling;

    spell_check(dictionary, article, misspelling);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your type WrongWord has a char array with MAX_LENGTH_OF_WORD elements,

```
typedef struct WrongWord WrongWord;
struct WrongWord {
    char word[MAX_LENGTH_OF_WORD];
    ll pos;
};
```

But you, you are copying strings using strcpy, instead of using strncpy. An overflow of this array can be the cause of the SEGFAULT.  It is great practice to use strncpy.

I think another mistake could be:

Here you are allocating memory just for a pointer, not for the whole struct:

```
WrongWord *wrong_word_list[MAX_NUMBER_OF_WRONG_WORDS];
wrong_word_list[wrong_word_count] = malloc(sizeof wrong_word_list[0]);
```

Replacing both malloc from:

```
wrong_word_list[wrong_word_count] = malloc(sizeof wrong_word_list[0]);
```

to:

```
wrong_word_list[wrong_word_count] = malloc(sizeof (WrongWord));
```

I have the following output:

```
" 34
- 45 45
bible 15
bill 43
domain 29
feeding 70
from 36
his 78
james 9
king 4
mcginnis 48
ministries 57
public 22
sheep 82
```

Comment: The MAX_LENGTH_OF_WORD is big enough.

Comment: Yeah I have fixed that earlier, but still got segfault.

Comment: `strncpy` is not any better, it will just create a non-null-terminated string leading to other problems